# Install twig/extensions on a Symfony 4 or Symfony 5 new project

Tags: symfony, twig, composer-php, symfony4, twig-extension

I'm preparing to migrate a huge website from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4.4.
To do this, I'm starting from a new fresh installation of Symfony 4.4, and as the intial project requires the use of Twig Extensions I try to install it on this new Symfony 4.4 project.
But composer indicates `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages`.

The error message is obvious, but I don't understand why this situation happens on a fresh symfony 4.4 project.

What I tried :

- I create a new Symfony `symfony new --full --version=lts testproject` that installed Symfony 4.4 and right after `composer require twig/extensions` => `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`
- I create a new Symfony `symfony new --full testproject` that installed Symfony 5.0 and right after `composer require twig/extensions` => `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`
- I tried with Symfony flex but same problem => `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

  - I retried after clearing the composer cache but no change.

This worked :
- I create a new Symfony `symfony new --full --version=3.4 testproject` that installed Symfony 3.4 and right after `composer require twig/extensions` => OK

I understand that dependencies conflits occur for Symfony 4.4 and more, but according to Symfony doc [How to Write a custom Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/templating/twig_extension.html) no further actions are required and it should work.

What I'm missing ? Does someone faced the same problem ? Thanks

Comment: Apparently, you shouldn't be eager to use twig/extensions anymore, as it'd be deprecated soon: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions/issues/262#issuecomment-561035271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it seems that running `composer require twig/extensions` is no more required to create custom Twig Extensions in Symfony 4.
By default a new Symfony built with website skeleton owes a `use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;` as per required to create a twig extension like below one :

```
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('price', [$this, 'formatPrice']),
        ];
    }

    public function formatPrice($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're using Flex, you should install twig first:

```
composer req twig
```

then, do:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

I hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I tried your suggestion but it doesn't change the situation. I still not able to install twig/extensions package

Comment: It's a PHP requirements I guess, try to install this PHP extension: php-intl
because twig extension is built on top of it. good luck.

Comment: The right answer - you don't need "twig/extensions" anymore. use `Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension` for extending your custom extension.